# Harry made Sally. (induce to have sex=make)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Harry made Sally.

Does this sentence mean? They already slept together or Harry tried but not yet succeeded?

Comment: No. "Make" does not have any connotation at all of "inducing to have sex".

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why do you say so? That meaning is listed in multiple major dictionaries.

Comment: Harry constructured Sally. I suspect you wanted to say *Harry* **made out** *with Sally*

Comment: Google *make out* It's a phrasal verb with more than one meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I understand you have been digging down into your dictionary and have found a definition of "make".  You need to look at the usage notes and context.

Basically "make" means "construct", "create", "constitute" etc.  But like many common verbs it has lots of extra uses, such as "cause to be" or "induce into the mafia".

Now one of the *rare, obsolete, slang, euphemistic* meanings is "engage in sexual intercourse with".  If you are a 1930s gangster you might say

> I met Betty in a clip joint in the Apple. She was as cute as a bug's ear and she'd be a hard dame for Joe like me to make.

As you are not a 1930s gangster, avoid this euphemism,  nobody will understand if you say "Harry made Sally".  But if you were, it would mean that they had had sex.

Comment: "But if you were, it would mean that they had had sex." Not necessarily. "Make" also has other meanings when used in this way.

Comment: Of course make has other meanings!  But in this meaning it is "had sex" not "failed to have sex".